# How to Select two values from one value

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return a collection of strings where every second record is "0" similar to this:

```
        foreach (Customer c in customers)
        {
            yield return c.Name;
            yield return "0";
        }
```

I started:

```
customers.Select(c => new
                                      {
                                          c.Name,
                                          Second = "0"
                                      }).???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need SelectMany:

```
var resultList = 
    customers.SelectMany(c => new[] {c.Name, "0"});
```

this takes your source list, and for each item, inserts a "0" after it.

Comment: I doubted, then I tested. Neat.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any overload of `Select` or any other built-in extension method I know of that would do this kind of thing automatically for you.  You could write your own extension for it though:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWithSeparator<T, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, TResult> selector,
        TResult separator)
    {
        if (selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            yield return selector(item);
            yield return separator;
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var customerNames = customers.SelectWithSeparator(c => c.Name, "0");
```

Answer (score 1):

from c in customers
select new { 
  Name = c.Name,
  Second = 0
}

or 
customers
.Select(c=> new 
  {
   Name = c.Name,
   Second = "0"
  }

Either one of these will give you an IQueryable. You can get a list by using the .ToList() extension.

> But then what?

What do you want to do after this?

Comment: I want a collection of strings where every second record is "0"

Comment: I see. What is wrong with your first aproach? Are you asking how to do it with lambda expressions?

Comment: Yes, I want to lose that foreach!

Answer (score 1):

Replace .??? with a semi-colon and you'll get an `IEnumerable<'a>`, where 'a is an anonymous type representing your customer's name and the value you hardcoded.

```
var query = customers.Select(c => new { Id = c.Name, Second = 0 });
foreach (var item in query)
{
   // work with item.Name and item.Second
}
```

Edit: To get what you want from your comments, you can do this, which you've basically already written. Just wrap it up in a function returning an `IEnumerable<string>`

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetCustomerNames(List<Customer> customers)
{
    foreach (Customer c in customers)
    {
        yield return c.Name;
        yield return "0";
    }
}
```